# Rss Feed, generating the image

Tags: php, rss

I am trying to generate an RSS feed on my site using the code below. The rss is appearing but I am having two issues:

1. When the feed shows on my page the images do not show up, instead you see the img link appear directly on the page like this... `<a href="http://movies.nytimes.com/2011/11/18/movies/garbo-the-spy-about-juan-pujol-garcia-review.html?partner=rssnyt&emc=rss"><img src="http://graphics8.nytimes.com/images/2011/11/18/movies/18RDP_GARBO/18RDP_GARBO-thumbStandard.jpg" border="0" height="75" width="75" hspace="4" align="left"></a>`
2. How do I limit the amount of articles that appear on my site?

Here is the link to the RSS: [Spy RSS FEED](http://feed://topics.nytimes.com/topics/reference/timestopics/subjects/e/espionage/index.html?rss=1)
Here is the code I am using:

```
    <?php
$insideitem = false;
$tag = "";
$title = "";
$description = "";
$link = "";
$locations = array('http://topics.nytimes.com/topics/reference/timestopics/subjects/e/espionage/index.html?rss=1');
srand((float) microtime() * 10000000); // seed the random gen 
$random_key = array_rand($locations);
function startElement($parser, $name, $attrs) {
 global $insideitem, $tag, $title, $description, $link;
 if ($insideitem) {
  $tag = $name;
 } elseif ($name == "ITEM") {
  $insideitem = true;
 }
}
function endElement($parser, $name) {
 global $insideitem, $tag, $title, $description, $link;
 if ($name == "ITEM") {
  printf("<dt><b><a href='%s' target=new>%s</a></b></dt>",
  trim($link),htmlspecialchars(trim($title)));
  printf("<dt>%s</dt><br><br>",htmlspecialchars(trim($description)));
  $title = "";
  $description = "";
  $link = "";
  $insideitem = false;
 }
}
function characterData($parser, $data) {
 global $insideitem, $tag, $title, $description, $link;
 if ($insideitem) {
 switch ($tag) {
  case "TITLE":
  $title .= $data;
  break;
  case "DESCRIPTION":
  $description .= $data;
  break;
  case "LINK":
  $link .= $data;
  break;
 }
 }
}
$xml_parser = xml_parser_create();
xml_set_element_handler($xml_parser, "startElement", "endElement");
xml_set_character_data_handler($xml_parser, "characterData");
$fp = fopen($locations[$random_key], 'r')
 or die("Error reading RSS data.");
while ($data = fread($fp, 4096))
 xml_parse($xml_parser, $data, feof($fp))
  or die(sprintf("XML error: %s at line %d",
   xml_error_string(xml_get_error_code($xml_parser)),    
   xml_get_current_line_number($xml_parser)));
fclose($fp);
xml_parser_free($xml_parser);
?>
```

Comment: Did you write that code yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `endElement()`, when outputting the feed content, it calls `printf("<dt>%s</dt><br><br>",htmlspecialchars(trim($description)));`

If you remove the `htmlspecialchars` function, then it should display images and other html properly instead of converting `<` to `&lt;` etc.

Given that code, there is no built in way to limit the number of feeds.  Nytimes may have an option you can pass as part of the query string that restricts the number of results, but I am not sure about that.

A quick fix would be to add a global variable called `$numShown` or something like that, and at the beginning of `endElement()`, you can increment it, and the check to see if it is above some value and if so just `return` prior to all the `printf` calls to output the feed item.

```
<?php

function endElement($parser, $name) {
    global $insideitem, $tag, $title, $description, $link, $numShown;

    if ($name == "ITEM") {
        $numShown++;

        if ($numShown >= 5) {
            return ;
        }

        printf ( "<dt><b><a href='%s' target=new>%s</a></b></dt>", trim ( $link ), htmlspecialchars ( trim ( $title ) ) );
        printf ( "<dt>%s</dt><br><br>", trim ( $description ) );
        $title = "";
        $description = "";
        $link = "";
        $insideitem = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I removed what you said to show the image and now the feed is really messed up and shows everything as a single block of text, no pictures, and no titles.

Comment: If you add `printf("<div style='clear: both'></div>");` after the $description is printed, the formatting should be fixed.

Comment: you told me to remove to remove that section.. what do you mean after?

Comment: I only meant for you to remove the usage of htmlspecialchars when printing the description.  See the paste [here](http://pastebin.com/UCu16024) for the full code.